# maven: does not download extension written by myself

Tags: maven

I am not so deep into maven but had to write an extension.
I successfully deployed and it is present.

```
https://www.simuline.eu/RepositoryMaven/eu/simuline/qMngmnt/0.0.3/
```

Also the version fits.
But nevertheless, when trying to use,

```
Unresolvable build extension: Plugin eu.simuline:qMngmnt:0.0.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
eu.simuline:qMngmnt:jar:0.0.3 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

In my pom i have:

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>publicRepoAtSimuline</id>
      <name>repo at simuline</name>
      <url>https://www.simuline.eu/RepositoryMaven</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

and I use it at the following places:

```
<build>
  <extensions>
      <extension>
    <groupId>eu.simuline</groupId>
    <artifactId>qMngmnt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3</version>
      </extension>
...
<plugins>
...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2</version>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
          <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
       <!-- 8.15 has security issue ans seemingly line lengths are wrong -->
             <version>10.1</version><!-- TBD: make 8.30, 9.1, 10.1 work -->
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
          <groupId>eu.simuline</groupId>
          <artifactId>qMngmnt</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
      </dependencies>
...

<dependencies>
   <dependency><!-- TBD: clarify: for spotbugs: necessary? -->
      <groupId>eu.simuline</groupId>
      <artifactId>qMngmnt</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.3</version>
      <!--scope>provided</scope-->
    </dependency>
```

Interesting: if i build a new version, `qMngmnt-0.0.4-SNAPSHOT`
then of course it is locally installed, and all works fine.
So I have the impression, download never worked but i did not realize so far.

What is wrong?

By the way: I use another artifact as an artifact item
but neither as a dependency nor as an extension and it works just fine.

Comment: First I would ask: Why have you written extension? What kind of problem do you have?

Comment: Have you tried running maven with `-X` to see any detailed errors?